# How to hide admin product form tabs for specific admin user?

Tags: magento2, php, knockoutjs, jquery

I want to have an admin user who would only be able to view the 'Images And Videos' and 'Search Engine Optimiation' in the admin product edit form.
[image]

I tried the following.
Created `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/catalog_product_edit.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="page.main.actions">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Permission" name="admin.permission" template="Vendor_Module::product_edit.phtml" after="-" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Created block file `app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Permission.php`

```php
use Magento\Backend\Block\Template;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session as AdminSession;

class Permission extends Template
{
    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * @param Context      $context
     * @param AdminSession $adminSession
     * @param array        $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        AdminSession $adminSession,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->adminSession = $adminSession;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCurrentAdminUserRole()
    {
        return $this->adminSession->getUser()->getRole()->getRoleName();
    }
}
```

Added template at `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/product_edit.phtml`

```html
<?php 
/**
 * @var $block \Vendor\Module\Block\Admin\Permission
 */
?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "adminProductPermission": {
                "role":"<?= $block->getCurrentAdminUserRole() ?>"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Added my js in require js `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/requirejs-config.js`

```javascript
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            adminProductPermission:'Vendor_Module/js/permission'
        }
    }
};
```

And finally in the JS file `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/web/js/permission.js`

```javascript
define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    return function(config) {
        var userRole = config.role;
        if(userRole == 'SEO') {
            $('.fieldset-wrapper div:not([data-index="gallery"]):not([data-index="search-engine-optimization"])').hide();
        }
    }
});
```

This is not working , as I believe the form is being loaded by KO js and it is being loaded after my js executed.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your permission.js this file code to the below code.

```
define([
'jquery'
], function ($) {
   return function(config) {
        var userRole = config.role;
        console.log(userRole);
        if(userRole == 'SEO') {
            setTimeout(function() {
                 $('[data-index="gallery"]').hide();
                 $('[data-index="search-engine-optimization"]').hide();
            }, 2000);
        }
    }
});
```

After applying the below commands.

```
sudo php bin/magento s:up && sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile && sudo php bin/magento s:static-content:de -f && sudo php bin/magento c:f && sudo chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/
```

Please try this code. let me know this is working or not. if my solution is working then accept my answer and give an upvote.

thanks

Comment: `setTimeout` works. Please update your answer to hide all the elements except 'gallery' & 'search-engine-optimisation'. Your code block hides the ones I require to show.

Answer (score 0):

Using `setTimeout` from Mohit's answer, the Js is now applying to the code. Following is my code for file `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/web/js/permission.js`

```javascript
define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    return function(config) {
        var userRole = config.role;
        if(userRole == 'SEO') {
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('.entry-edit.form-inline > div:not([data-index="gallery"]):not([data-index="search-engine-optimization"])').hide();
            }, 5000);
        }
    }
});
```

Had to do slight modification to the element selector as well.

One flaw in this I found is that if the page load is slower that the `setTimeout`, the elements will remain visible.

Comment: i am also implementing your code in my module so it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps to make specific tab invisible without use to setTimeout.

- Remove requirejs-config.js
- add window.config global variable in product_edit.phtml so you can access role in js file
- Add new file with below code in product_form.xml, this file located in view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_form.xml

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="salable_quantity">
        <field name="check_role" sortOrder="40" formElement="hidden" component="Vendor_Module/js/permission">
            <settings>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">For check the role</label>
            </settings>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Update below code in permission.js

```
define([
'underscore',
'uiRegistry',
'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract'], function (_, uiRegistry, abstract) {
'use strict';
return abstract.extend({
    initialize : function (){
        uiRegistry.get(function(component){
                if(component.componentType == 'fieldset'){
                    var fieldName = uiRegistry.get('index = '+ component.index);
                    fieldName.visible(false);
                }
        });
        this._super();
        return this;
    }
}); 
});
```

Comment: Your answer is not clear to me. Where is the `product_edit.phtml` file ? And what are the contents of the file ? You have shared xml content for that file

Comment: <script>
       window.adminrole = '<?php echo $block->getCurrentAdminUserRole(); ?>';
 </script>

Comment: Path is same as you have used for this file.

Comment: I have updated the file path in answered

Comment: Thanks, will try this out